# How to upgrade Tomcat on linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, centos

My current running Tomcat is as following

```
Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/5.5.36
Servlet Specification Version : 2.4
JSP version : 2.0
```

I need to change it to

```
Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
Servlet Specification Version : 3.1
JSP version : 2.3
```

I downloaded Tomcat version 8 and I have following, how can I run Tomcat 8 and make it default of the server?

```
root@server [/opt]# ls
./                           cpanel/                    pcre/
../                          curlssl/                   php_with_imap_client/
apache-tomcat-8.0.18/        jdk1.7.0_75/               suphp/
apache-tomcat-8.0.18.tar.gz  jdk-7u75-linux-x64.tar.gz  xml2/
```

I tried following command but it failed.

```
root@server [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/bin]# ./startup.sh
Cannot find apache-tomcat-8.0.18/bin/setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program
```

~/.bashrc

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64"
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH

export CATALINA_HOME="apache-tomcat-8.0.18"
```

Java Version

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.4.0.el6_6-x86_64 u75-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
root@server [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/bin]#
```

O/S

```
Linux server.myproject.com 2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 17 
23:56:34 BST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear...make it a default server to do what exactly? if you want it to start on bootup you'll have to manually call it from a ~/.login script or a ~/.bashrc. You'd first make sure that java is in your path then you'd do /path/to/catalina.sh <args>. If you have other scripts/programs that look for catalina.sh in your path to start it you'd have to make sure that it shows up before the outdated version

Comment: Stop.  Before you *consider* upgrading your Tomcat version that much, you  need to do an audit of all of the changes between Tomcat versions.  Things may "just work"; things may not work as well as they did; things may entirely break and leave you confused as to why.  **Tread carefully**.

Comment: @Qwertyzw currently Tomcat 5.5.36 is running, I need to stop that and rather run Tomcat 8. Question is updated.

Comment: find catalina.sh corresponding to the old server and do ./catalina.sh stop. I suggest you listen to what the people are trying to tell you before you start the migration though. You'll need to do other things if you're migrating web applications, but if you're just experimenting with things  this will suffice.

Comment: @Qwertyzw I was just researching to see what I should do, I am wondering what else should I consider in migrating

Comment: Among other things you'll need to take a look at the jdk requirements of the new server. Look here http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: @Qwertyzw thanks for your comment, based on table of the link you provided, I should upgrade Servlet Spec, JSP Spec, EL Spec, Web Socket Spect as well. How should I update those? :)

Comment: @Makoto what other factors should I consider? I know that I need to change servlet and JSP specs but do not know how

Comment: There's entirely too much to your individual situation for me to even take a guess at.  I don't know anything about what external libraries you're using, what other components you're using, or if they've updated their libraries to be compatible with the changes to `TreeMap` in Java 7, let alone anything in Java 8.   The onus is on ***you*** to audit your platform.  It's a huge undertaking, and is entirely too broad to broach here.

Comment: @Makoto thanks for your comment, how about ignoring the application and just consider migrating to Tomcat 8? What factors do I need to consider in migrating to new version?

Comment: @IvanT not yet, will let you know,

Answer (score 2):

The Tomcat startup.sh script uses $CATALINA_HOME to find setclasspath.sh, which is the cause of your failed startup. Therefore, $CATALINA_HOME needs to be an absolute path to your tomcat installation directory, e.g.

`export CATALINA_HOME="/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.18"`

If you plan on upgrading again, you might consider setting $CATALINA_HOME to /opt/tomcat, then you would create a symbolic link from /opt/tomcat to /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.18 or whatever future version you end up installing. Since you will likely have multiple environmental variables pointing to your tomcat directory, this gives you a single change point when updating references.

`ln -nsf /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.18 /opt/tomcat`